# Send personal message to facebook friend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm creating a service marketplace to offer and ask services.Users can contact each other via inbuilt message module.Here I'm planning to send message in receiver's  facebook account to notify the receiver about the new message in marketplace.People often use facebook and occasionally sign in marketplace site or check email.So I want to send a notification message in their facebook.

I went through [this](http://dalibornasevic.com/posts/35-how-to-send-private-messages-with-facebook-api) tutorial but it doesn't work for me. I think this is outdated as [facebook chat API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat) are depreciated.

Is there any other way to send private message to facebook friends. Any suggestion will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to send messages to friends. Users have to use the Messenger App or facebook.com.